# Magento flat product

Tags: magento

when trying to enable and reindex Product Flat Data - getting error from magento

> The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable
>   attributes. Currently there are 521 of them. Please reduce the number
>   of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module.

I can't understand what this means and from where magento gets this values.
In attributes I have only 321 different attributes so from where magento gets value of 521 currently used and where it takes limit for 64 of them???

thnx.

Comment: Curious - was this issue ever resolved or worked around?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::prepareFlatTable()` is throwing this exception, when your product has more than

```
<global>
    <catalog>
        <product>
            <flat>
                <max_index_count>64</max_index_count>
            </flat>
        </product>
    </catalog>
</global>
```

indexes. This maximum usually is defined in `app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc/config.xml` and matches the maximum number of 64 keys allowed by default mySQL installations, before they error with

```
ERROR 1069: Too many keys specified. Max 64 keys allowed
```

Your problem is not how many attributes your products have, but how many of them are *filterable and/or sortable* (except *all* your attributes are, of course).

Trace `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Flat_Indexer::getFlatIndexes()` to find out how Magento reaches a total of 521 indexes.

For a quick check you can also have a look at your `catalog_eav_attribute` table and check how many attributes are filterable (`is_filterable = 1`) and/or sortable (`used_for_sort_by` = 1)

Comment: thnx - will try to change mysql params and optimize attributes

Comment: Hi what could be the possible implications if we increase the maximum-indexes count to 80 or 100 for a database table ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249472/implication-in-increasing-mysql-maximum-keys-allowed-per-table

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting is coming from the following file:

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Product/Flat|Indexer.php

It appears that this limit is set in the Catalog config.xml file which is located in the following file:

/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/etc|config.xml

Doing a search for "max_index_count" you will find that this value is set to 64.

I am not sure why this limit is in place, but I have to imagine that they had a good reason for setting it to 64. On a DEVELOPMENT environment (I would suggest you do not try this on your live site before you understand what could happen) you could change this value and see what happens.

The number of indexes you have (the 521) is coming from the getFlatIndexes function in the Indexer.php file. I am guessing you are getting to 521 because you have your 321 + some additional ones that Magento uses by default.

If I had to guess, this limit is put in place to keep the flat catalog tables from getting too large horizontally. I am guessing there is a speed issue when the table gets too large.

Comment: thnx - will try to experement with this params

Comment: Hi what could be the possible implications if we increase the max-indexes count to 80 or 100 for the catalog product flat table ? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249472/implication-in-increasing-mysql-maximum-keys-allowed-per-table