# Error: The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable attributes. Currently there are 66 of them

Tags: php, magento, reindex

In My Magento Backend Admin Panel:-

System -> Configuration -> Index Management -> Product Flat Data -> Reindex Data

It Shows Error :-
The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable attributes. Currently there are 66 of them. Please reduce the number of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module

This Error is their on My Live Magento Website. I Tried https://kb.magenting.com/content/20/94/en/solution-problem-with-reindexing-process-for-product-flat-data-indexes.html But No Luck.

And The Same Error is their On my Development Website also

The Flat Catalog module has a limit of 64 filterable and/or sortable attributes. Currently there are 66 of them. Please reduce the number of filterable/sortable attributes in order to use this module

I Don't want to reduce my filterable attribute By Selecting 'No' in 'Used for Sorting in Product Listing' in Catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes

I dont want to change configuration limit as it can slow down my website or any other problem with that because the person who answered here [Magento flat product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536222/magento-flat-product) doesnot know of its result

Thankyou For Everyone who will Help Me with This Problem in Advance ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento flat product](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536222/magento-flat-product)

Comment: You have hit a MySQL limit, you can try this http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65519/flat-catalog-module-has-a-limit-of-64-filterable-and-or-sortable-attributes-ho but may run into issues mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10536222/magento-flat-product which is that the MySQL default is `Max 64 keys allowed`

Comment: Please I Dont go with this because The Person Who answered there does not know its results so If Fiasco Labs You Can Give Me another Solution